# Reading Coordinates From A Text File to Loop?

Tags: java, arrays, object, point

So I have to write a program where I am reading coordinates that are contained in a text file that are in my present working directory.  My question is how do I make an array of Point objects to store those coordinates in after I have read the text file? This is my code so far for reading the file and the while loop..

---

```
    try {

    // create the file reader instance
    FileReader fReader = new FileReader(fileName);

    // create a scanner to scan through the file
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (fReader);

    // loop 
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int i = 0;
            int x = scan.nextInt();
            int y = scan.nextInt();
            array[i] = new Point(x,y);

            i++;
        }


    // close the reader
        fReader.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrays need to be initialized to the size of data you need to put it them. If you don't know the size, you can create one that is large enough to handle all data but you are wasting space that way. You can use a list or another collection and then once all the data is read, you can convert to array once you know the size.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how many points you will read in advance you can use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) :

Declare and initialize it before the while loop:

`ArrayList<Point> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();`

And in the loop use `arraylist.add(point);` to add a point to it.

At last, if you really need an array you can convert your ArrayList using:

`Point[] foo = arraylist.toArray(new Point[arraylist.size()]);`

Comment: So how would I call the file in main to store the coordinates inside of the array in my above method? Just call the method and pass the file name?

Comment: You would call it exactly like you have in your code. Instead of initializing the array, you would use the array list as mentioned. In the end, you can convert the array list to an array.

Comment: Any reason I'm getting an error symbol not found under the array[i] = new Point(x,y)?

Comment: On the code sample you gave the `array` variable is not declared anywhere. That's a very good reason for a "symbol not found" error.